# Why and where is `ä` an unexpected token in R and how should I deal with it?

Tags: r

The following function concatenates words of an input expression and prints them as strings:

```
f <- function(e) {
  e <- deparse(substitute(e))
  gsub(" \\+ ", "", e)
} 

f(a + e)
[1] "ae"
f(ä + e)
[1] "äe"
```

When I place the same function definition and calls into an .rmd file, however, RStudio shows an error:

[image]

When knitting the .rmd file the output looks ok:

[image]

---

My complete `.rmd` file:

```
f <- function(e) {
  e <- deparse(substitute(e))
  gsub(" \\+ ", "", e)
} 

f(a + e)
f(ä + e)
```

---

*Now my questions are:*

- Why is `ä` inside an `.rmd` file an *unexpected token*, while it is fine inside an `.r` file?
- Why does `knit` still work if there are unexpected tokens?

*And a bit more vague:*

- Is it somewhat safe to allow *ä, ö & ü* inside a DSL notation (that's what I'm working on in the big picture..)?
- Can I parse `.r` files for *ä, ö & ü* in order to throw an error from within my DSL?

Comment: Since this is so specific to the Rstudio editor, a better place to ask this question would be: https://community.rstudio.com/

Comment: @MrFlick: Thx for the hint. Placed it [there](https://community.rstudio.com/t/why-and-where-is-a-an-unexpected-token-in-r-and-how-should-i-deal-with-it/26496).

Comment: For me, it was simple, I **renamed** my r file to r markdown file by adding the ***.Rmd*** extension at the end, however, the right way is to create an r markdown file from scratch.  Which will have a pink color logo.